# RegEx to Validate Password (1 Lowercase, 1Uppercase, 1 Digit, NoSpaces)

Tags: regex, passwords, character

I'm trying to create a RegExpression to meet the criteria below;

- at least 1 Lowercase
- at least 1 Uppercase
- at least 1 Digit
- No Spaces
- Minimum 8 characters
- No special characters

So far I got this;

```
^(?=.{8,})(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.\s).*$
```

However I can not get it to work.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.
I was never good at puzzles :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're nearly there; it's just the `.*` at the end that ignores your "no spaces/special characters" rules, and the `(?=.\s)` lookahead is wrong (you probably meant `(?!.*\s)` or `(?=\S*$)`).

But you don't need that lookahead anyway because you can simply specify which characters are allowed (and enforce the "8 characters minimum" rule there, too):

```
^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)[A-Za-z\d]{8,}$
```

But why do you want to keep users from using non-alphanumeric characters in their passwords?

Comment: @user1595357: Is that C#? In that case, that's the preferred syntax because it allows you to use backslashes without having to escape them.

Comment: Why? That password is valid  for this expression?

Comment: I see, your wording is not so accurate @user1595357

Comment: @TimPietzcker I added a point to your answer, the wording of the question confused me but your answer works.

Comment: @TimPietzcker The passwords are being set in ActiveDirectory and the PasswordPolicy property in AD does not allow special characters. Thanks for your help